# Make iOS app IPV6 compliant

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

## Aim:

I would like to make the app IPV6 compliant. I have hard-cored IP as http://50.1.1.1:8222/live to stream music from my radio, and I do this with avkit like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://50.1.1.1:8222/live")

 playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)

 player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Is there any way to bypass it or I have to change my server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Apple's Developer Support. Go to Apple's Resolution Center and talk to them about how you can solve your issue.

Comment: So nobody will know the answer of this problem? And why is offtopic if I have to put a sort of a code to bypass it?

Comment: Your app needs to work on an IPv6 network.  Most IPv6 networks will be able to access a 6to4 proxy, so you should be able to work without explicitly supporting IPv6 on your server, but you need to perform [the required testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16).  At the very least you should use DNS rather than a hard-coded IP address.

Comment: Remember, its not just about passing Apple's approval process; your users may well be on IPv6 networks and Apple wants to ensure that apps in the app store work for them.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you I will read it and share the results

Comment: @Paulw11 I read the article, if I'm getting this right I just have to create a "hotspot" with a stimulative ipv6 network and the app will then pass the review?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth This is not off-topic. It's a technical question asking to make it compatible with an IPv6 network.

Comment: No, you can create a hotspot in order to create an IPv6 network that you can use to test your app and make sure that it does work on IPv6; if it doesn't then you still need to solve the problem.  IPv6 may not be the issue, Apple are just letting you know about the environment in which your app was tested in case that is a factor.  For example, if `http://50.1.1.1:8222/live` is your actual URL, I cannot connect to it,

Comment: I believe it *is*, because OP is not asking how to make it IPv6, but how to bypass the rejection, @rmaddy

Comment: @mikevorisis Edit your question just a little so the focus is on how to make your code work with IPv6. No need to mention anything about your app being rejected. That will make the close-voters happier and it makes for a more specific question.

Comment: @Paulw11  I changed my router ip version to only ipv6 (from ipv4/ipv6) and my app didn't work so I believe its ipv6 the reason of rejection

Comment: Yay. Close vote retracted.

Comment: @mikevorisis that may not be the right thing to do; your ISP needs to support IPv6 in order for you to use IPv6 only on your network.  The Apple document I linked to shows how to create an IPv6 network that translates through your IPv4 network so that you can test for connectivity from an IPv6 network without having a pure IPv6 environment.  You should also test running your app from a public network, such as 3G/4G connection to ensure it can connect to your server to rule out any firewalls etc.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok then I will test it as they say (with 3g/4g my app works fine)

Comment: @Paulw11 I did the sharing as the tutorial and I have access in my app...so It isn't an ipv6 problem right?

Comment: Probably not.  As I said, if `http://50.1.1.1:8222/live` is your actual URL and not just something you put in the question, I can't connect to it.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you check the above url?

Comment: It works for me, but not when I switch to pure IPv6, but many sites don't work on pure IPv6 (although IPv6-test.com does).  You should definitely use a domain name instead of an IP address though, for a start.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thank you I will try to reupload and if they reject me again I will ask for a TSI, when I finish I will write what happened (Thanks for your time)

Comment: Eventually I re-uploaded the app and it passed the review...Thank you all for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the IP address could you use a host name.

## Refer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1